# Maven Goal(s) Failing to Execute

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am attempting to get adam (https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam) up and running on a Windows machine. I currently have hadoop and spark working natively, and was attempting to build adam using maven but am receiving the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] ADAM_2.10 .......................................... FAILURE [ 14.887 s]
[INFO] ADAM_2.10: Core .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ADAM_2.10: APIs for Java ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ADAM_2.10: CLI ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ADAM_2.10: Assembly ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.018 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-26T17:18:31-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/261M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project adam-parent_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4, org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.3: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed: Tag mismatch! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project adam-parent_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4, org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.3: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4, org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.3: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4, org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.3: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:400)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:372)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4, org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.3: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: GET request of: org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:285)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:531)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:353)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:524)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1023)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:960)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:479)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2377)
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:461)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(InputRecord.java:172)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1015)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

The error looks to be related to a tag mismatch, but I am unsure of how to resolve this...

Install Command Line Parameters:

`set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

Comment: If [the docs](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam#building-from-source) about building it results in a failure, I'd suggest creating an issue for it so that the maintainers can fix it...

Comment: Appreciate the response Tunaki - sadly I ended up just using a vagrant VM.

Answer (score 0):

jvm version can be issue ..I changed env jdk version from 1.8 to 1.6 worked for me